# %27 error appearing in url link

Tags: php, mysql, url

when user register to my site and activation link is sent to their email...it showing page not found error

orignal activation link

`http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email='akshaypp%40mail.com'&key='d6433fa355d81e942b3ba0b845de089e'`

its show like

`tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email= **%27** akshaypp%40mail.com **%27** &key= **%27** d6433fa355d81e942b3ba0b845de089e **%27**`

tell me how to fix this code....and remove that **%27%** for link

my php code

```
$message = "To Activate your account, please click on this link: \n \n";
$message .= "http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email='".urlencode($email)."'&key='".$activation."'";
mail($email,'Activation of your EESA Account',$message);
```

Comment: You can use urldecode to do the opposite of what urlencode does

Answer (score 5):

Never put quotes in url, you might use a separator line dash or underscore, if is not need separator, then don't use.

Instead of

```
http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email='blah@blah.com'
```

use

```
http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email=blah@blah.com   // quotes removed !
```

or in your PHP

```
$message .= "http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&key=".$activation;   //without '
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are enclosing your parameters with `''`. This is not necessary when using the `GET` method.

Fixed code would be like this:

```
$message = "To Activate your account, please click on this link: \n \n";
$message .= "http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&key=".$activation."";
mail($email,'Activation of your EESA Account',$message);
```

---

A little bit more explanation to the *mysterious* `%27`code. When you translate your string `$message` into an url, [special symbols](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) are [converted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) into *url friendly expressions*. The expression `%27` stands for a `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the parameters. You don't need to enclose the parameters in quotes as the parameter name itself identifies the value (`$_GET['key']` will display the value of parameter key).

```
$message .= "http://tc14.wceeesa.org/activate.php?email=".urlencode($email)."&key=".$activation;
```